# Filling a matrix efficiently

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, dplyr, reshape2

I have data where outcomes of treatments with a set of drugs on a set of subjects were measured across a set of hospitals. (#drugs > #subjects > #hospitals)

```
subjects <- paste("S",1:100,sep="_")
drugs <- paste("D",1:1000,sep="_")
```

My `data.frame` has in each each line a `drug`, `subject`, `hospital`, `outcome` combination:

```
df <- expand.grid(subject=subjects,drug=drugs,stringsAsFactors=F)
hospitals <- paste("H",1:10,sep="_")
df$hospital <- rep(sapply(hospitals,function(h) rep(h,10)),200)
set.seed(1)
df$outcome <- runif(nrow(df),0,100)
```

Now I want to build a `matrix` where each row is a unique `hospital` `subject` combination and each column is a unique `hospital` `drug` combination. Here's probably a not optimally efficient way to build this matrix:

```
df$hospital.subject <- paste(df$hospital,df$subject,sep=":")
df$hospital.drug <- paste(df$hospital,df$drug,sep=":")

hospital.subject <- unique(paste(df$hospital,df$subject,sep=":"))
hospital.drug <- unique(paste(df$hospital,df$drug,sep=":"))

mat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(hospital.subject, function(x){
  hospital.subject.df <- dplyr::filter(df,hospital.subject==x)
  res <- rep(NA,length(hospital.drug))
  match.idx <- match(hospital.drug,hospital.subject.df$hospital.drug)
  res[which(!is.na(match.idx))] <- hospital.subject.df$outcome[match.idx[which(!is.na(match.idx))]]
  return(res)
}))
rownames(mat) <- hospital.subject
colnames(mat) <- hospital.drug
```

So question #1 is how to build this matrix more efficiently if this is possible.

Now, since the matrix is sparse I'd like to impute each `hospital.subject` combination with missing values in their `hospital.drug` combination, i.e., in which these `subjects` were not observed, according to the `hospital.drug` combinations in which they were observed, from a normal distribution with `mean` = `median` and `sd` = `mad` of these observed `hospital.subject` combinations.

In other words, for example for `subjects[1:10]`, which were only observed in `hospitals[1]`, fill in for `hospitals[2:10]` from `hospitals[1]` for each respective `drug`. That means:

`mat[1:10,2:10] <- rnorm(90,median(mat[1:10,1]),mad(mat[1:10,1]))`

`mat[1:10,12:20] <- rnorm(90,median(mat[1:10,1]),mad(mat[1:10,1]))`

and so one and for the next hospitals (rows in mat), e.g.,

`mat[31:40,2:10] <- rnorm(90,median(mat[31:40,1]),mad(mat[31:40,1]))`

`mat[31:40,12:20] <- rnorm(90,median(mat[31:40,1]),mad(mat[31:40,1]))`

using `for` loops I'd do it this way:

```
for(h in 1:length(hospitals)){
  row.idx <- which(grepl(paste0(hospitals[h],":"),hospital.subject)==T)
  col.idx <- which(grepl(paste0(hospitals[h],":"),hospital.drug)==T)
  for(i in 1:length(col.idx)){
    drug <- strsplit(hospital.drug[col.idx[i]],split=":")[[1]][2]
    impute.idx <- which(grepl(paste0(":",drug,"$"),hospital.drug,perl=T)==T)[-col.idx[i]]
    mat[row.idx,impute.idx] <- rnorm(length(row.idx)*length(impute.idx),mean=median(mat[row.idx,col.idx[i]]),sd=mad(mat[row.idx,col.idx[i]]))
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient and elegant way to achieve this?

One more thing, my real data is less well organized than in this example in the sense that the number of subjects in each hospital is not identical, and in addition there are subjects treated with the same drug in more than one hospital.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
df$hos.sub=paste(df$hospital,df$subject)
df$hos.dru=paste(df$hospital,df$drug)

ind1 <- list(factor(df$hos.sub),factor(df$hos.dru))
res<-tapply(df[,"outcome"],ind1,mean)
head(res[,1:10])

> head(res[,1:9])
           H_1 D_1  H_1 D_10 H_1 D_100 H_1 D_1000 H_1 D_101  H_1 D_102 H_1 D_103 H_1 D_104 H_1 D_105
H_1 S_1  26.550866 83.189899  6.516364   45.77171  6.471249 26.6257392  81.14044  9.088058  67.64499
H_1 S_10  6.178627  4.288589 45.675309   77.90078  3.338293 95.5751769  92.02642 49.810641  14.31814
H_1 S_2  37.212390 76.684275 27.743618   21.32599 67.661240 66.0476814  82.46891 97.271288  88.86986
H_1 S_3  57.285336 27.278032 60.041069   55.22206 73.537169 21.2416518  91.60083 85.267414  95.01507
H_1 S_4  90.820779 18.816330 27.314448   13.21052 11.129967  0.5266102  72.34151 49.899330  91.69972
H_1 S_5  20.168193 22.576183 94.148905   44.60504  4.665462 10.2902506  91.02545 27.440370  90.51900
```

Comment: I don't think this is imputing the way I'm describing in my question